# Merge an untracked directory into the tracked directory

Tags: svn, git, merge

I have two version of the source directories where

`/d1` is tracked by git but outdated

`/d2` is not tracked by anything but the most up-to-date

What is the best way to merge `/d2` into `/d1`?

Answer (score 0):

what speaks against copying d2 over d1 and then creating a new commit objects?
just make sure you do not overwrite your `.git`-directory. doing backups is a good exercise here

```
cp -aT d2 d1
git status
# shows lots of changed files
git add -u # or git add -A depending if you want to add new files as well
git commit -m "committing a whole lot of changes from my untracked directory. i wonder why it got untracked in the first place?"
```