# git create patch of only my changes

Tags: git

I would like to do something fundamentally similar to this question:

[Merge an untracked directory into the tracked directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009085/merge-an-untracked-directory-into-the-tracked-directory)

However, the answer there is not particularly helpful for my situation.

Basically, a colleague sent me his version of the code as a zip file.  His version should be quite ahead of my version, but I can't just use his version because there are a couple of bug-fixes in my version that I don't believe are in his.  What I would like to do is create a patch which contains only my contributions to the code and attempt to patch his (untracked) version with my changes.

Is this the same thing as checking out the revision before I started working on the code in a new branch, copying his files into that repo and committing it as a new branch, then merging that branch with mine?  If so, how would I go about finding the first commit that I made in the directory in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git log` to show all the commits that have affected a specific path:

```
git log -- path/to/interesting/dir
```

Since you're only interested in your own commits, you'll also need the `--author` option:

```
git log --author=mgilson -- path/to/interesting/dir
```

The first commit in the directory is the last one in the list, which you could find with a combination of the `--oneline` option and `tail`:

```
git log --author=mgilson --oneline -- path/to/interesting/dir | tail -n1
```

Comment: That's the first commit in the directory -- I want the first commit that **I** made in that directory. Something like `git log --oneline -- path/to/dir | grep mgilson | tail -1` (but that doesn't work since the author of the commit isn't in the output with --oneline)

Comment: @mgilson: It wasn't clear from your question that there were commits from other users in the repository.  I've updated my answer to also provide author filtering.

Comment: Thanks, that'll do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the same thing as checking out the revision before I started working on the code in a new branch, copying his files into that repo and committing it as a new branch, then merging that branch with mine?

Yes it should be the same, with the additional benefit to keep everything in the same referential.

> how would I go about finding the first commit that I made in the directory in question?

A **[`git bisect`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git)** would be useful, in order to find the first "bad" commit (ie one where your directory exists).

Comment: The directory exists in both cases -- I want to know when I first committed to that directory. -- It seems like I should just be able to grep git-log or something...